# SQL query Google sheet - equals / not equal

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I would like to query db that will returen all the DB that **not equal to a range** of values (in cells A1:A10)

Can i query not equal to a range ?

QUERY(Cons!E2:T,"SELECT O,J WHERE O IS NOT IN A1:A10"))

Comment: You could try: `=QUERY(Cons!E2:T,"SELECT O,J WHERE O<>A2:A")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
=QUERY(Cons!E2:T,"SELECT O,J WHERE NOT O MATCHES '\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,A1:A10)&"\b'")
```

Comment: What is benefits of using `\b`?

Comment: `\b` is meant to prevent partial matches. For example, if there is `apple` in A1:A10, if we match `apple` it will also match things like `pineapple`, `applesauce` etc... If we match `\bapple\b` instead it will only match `apple`. I believe we may also need `.*` at the beginning and the end because if I recall correctly, the QUERY `matches` clause operates with implied `^` and `$`.